# Python Decorator to track and record the variable that got reassigned inside for-loop function

Tags: python

Suppose I have this function `first_5_mult_table` which print the first 5 times table given any number,

```
def first_5_mult_table(mult):  
    for i in range(1,6):
        value = i*mult
        print(value)
```

Now, I need decorator function to be able to record the value specific variable everytime it got reassigned, for this case variable `value`, so it could do something like this

```
def first_5_mult_table(mult):  
    for i in range(1,6):
        value = i*mult
        print(value)   
        # recorder.append(value)
```

so, I have tried to draft the following decorator function as `record_loop_func`, and assign new non-local variable list `recorder` which was hoped to append all of the value in every loop from `loop_func`

```
def outest_record_loop_func(var_name:list):
    
    def record_loop_func(loop_func):
        recorder = []
        def record_func(*args,**kwargs):
            # ....
            return # expected to return list of [5,10,15,20,30]


        return record_func
```

However, I'm running out of idea, and still don't know how to make my decorator be able to store all `value` from every loop into list `recorder`

So, my question is that Is there any possible ways to use decorator function to record all the `value` from every loops for any loop function
(for loop like someone record what I print out)

for example, when I run `first_5_mult_table(5)`, it would print all the value, and also return [5,10,15,20,25]

```
@record_loop_func(['value'])
def first_5_mult_table(mult):
    for i in range(1,6):
        value = i*mult
```

ps. I know you guys may wonder why don't I just declare a list recorder inside `first_5_mult_table`. The reason is for instance it can collect a specific variable inside each loop, says there are variables `value`,`index`, and others, but I want to keep record only `value`, so, that is what I really want it to be

Comment: No, it's not possible without changing logic of the function. Decorators treat functions they decorate as a black-box - they don't have access to its inner workings.

Comment: "I want to keep record only value, so, that is what I really want it to be" - for what purpose? What are you ultimately hoping to achieve by caching the values?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen to trace and check whether if this function is doing and assign the specific variable right (just like logging the variable), says inside my loop have a ton of variable, I suspect one of those variable if it misbehaves

Comment: Sounds like you want [a debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), not a cache :)

Comment: @matszwecja Thank you for clarifying this, so decorator can only access only its input and output of its first class function, but not inside its logic

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm sorry for not being honest about the example, In fact, I just want to create module which have a utility function which is able to report to user about somewhat another function have done in each iteration, but if there is no better way than declare a list inside the function, then I give up on using decorator

Comment: @matszwecja In principle it *is* possible, because the decorator can recover the function’s AST by decompiling its bytecode, modify it, recompile it, evaluate the modified bytecode and execute the result of that. It’s complex and thus very rarely done, but it works.

Comment: "a utility function which is able to report to user about somewhat another function have done in each iteration" - @Wallika You might not be aware, but you're quite literally describing a debugger - it'll allow you to step into each iteration of the function and observe the local variable values :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for replying, I think there is some misconceptions here, the "user" in this case is not me, but some people who use my package, and I purposely want to plot those list in matplotlib.pyplot  ;_; , not to just debug

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for new information, May I have any resources that tell us about this. <3

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Anyway I never use and know about that package pdb, it will be useful for some of my cases, Thank you again